# Rearranging HTML elements with PHP

Tags: php, html, replace

The RSS feed I read from was recently updated and messed up quite a few things, I fixed most of the issues but this I can't figure.

How the date was formatted previously:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            13 </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            July </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            2012 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How it is right now:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>13th July, 2012</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So:

1. Day Month and Year has to be separated in their own DIVs (most difficult)
2. "th" and "," needs to be removed (this is easy with str_replace)

Now the problem is I could do this with jQuery in minutes but it has to be **done with PHP** before it gets saved, and since the divs have no class/id its even more difficult for me.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: For this problem? Nothing cause I just can't figure how to separate these. Other issues I've fixed and str_replaces are no problem either.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `strip_tags` in PHP to get the date and then use `strtotime` to normalize the date?  Then you can generate whatever HTML you want.

Comment: This should get you somewhat in the right direction: `explode(',',  date('d,F,Y', strtotime('13th July, 2012')));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags` in PHP to get the date and then use `strtotime` to normalize the date.

Then you can generate whatever HTML you want.

EDIT: here is your solution:

```
<?php
//at this point, $string = the input you wish to modify
$string = "
<div>
    <div>
        <div>13th July, 2012</div>
    </div>
</div>
";

//get normalised time
$time = strtotime(trim(strip_tags($string)));

//with normalised time, generate your new output
echo "
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            ".date("d",$time)." </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            ".date("F",$time)." </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            ".date("Y", $time)." </div>
    </div>
</div>
";
?>
```

Comment: I already do and what I now have is the best output

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide you your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing the actual code for you, a solution would be:

- Use a DOM parser to get the information you need (the date `div` contents);
- `explode` on the space character;
- `(int)` the first number and `rtrim` the month to get rid of the comma.

Or use @Darrrrrren's solution which is way better...